# Can't get Frontend Search to work

Tags: search

Well, to be honest i am completely new, not only to Craft but to most PHP stuff as well.
I am currently trying to setup a search for my page but i seem to miss a crucial step and can not find any tutorials on what to do.

On my front/ index page i included

```
<form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
<input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

as stated in the Craft Documentation.

I have also set up a single page for my search results with the code from the Documentation as well:

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}
{% if entries|length %}
<p>{{ entries|length }} results:</p>
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>Your search for “{{ query }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
{% endif %}
```

So, now if i try to search at the index page and hit enter, it just reloads the index page with the search term

```
site.url/index.php?q=test
```

So for sure i am missing a step here and am not loading the right page. I guess it should be stated in {{ url('search/results') }}, but i have no idea what to put there.

Would be great if anybody could help me or at least point me to a tutorial that focuses on setting up a site search in Craft CMS.

Comment: In your code do you close the `<form>` as you aren't in your example

Comment: sure ;) it just got pushed to the next line and disappeared here, fixed that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the `<form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">` You define which page should be redirected to when the search form is submitted.

"search/results" would go to the search folder looking for the results.(html / twig).

If you want to redirect to another page you should name the folder (which is "search" now) then the template name. This can be static without creating a "Single" for that page.

If you did create a single that uses that template and you want to go through your single you can just put the slug of the created Single inside your form action.

**Example:**

You made a folder in craft/templates/ named: search, inside that folder you make a file named: results.

So the file structure would be craft/templates/search/results.twig and the form action would be: `<form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">`

This way you can just use the preset search template the craft docs offer you. You could also change "results.twig/html" to index.html and then your form action wouldn't need the /results so your action would look like:
`<form action="{{ url('search') }}">`

But I see you get redirect to /index.php/ aswell so I should try rmeoving that by changing your `.htaccess` file and maybe your general.php.

You can find instructions on how to do that here:
https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php